# Is there a way to detect wheter a pointer has been initialized or not in C?

Tags: c, pointers

I pass a pointer to my function but if this is not initialized I get, obviously, segmentation fault. I could solve this porblem by assigning `NULL` to that pointer when declared (or, in general, before passing it to my function), but if I wanted my funtion to detect that pointer is not initialized?

Comment: No, there is no way (other than assigning `NULL`) to determine is a pointer has a valid value.

Comment: Not possible. Initializing to NULL is what should be done.

Comment: Why would you even want that? Initializing pointers to null is exactly the way that is foreseen to ensure that a pointer does not point to anything valid.

Comment: Please explain why intialising to NULL is not an option. Without that explanation the question it unclear.

Comment: I am not defending him, but had similar issue years ago where I developed a function that was used by someone else, and that someone else did not initialize pointer neither was it set to null. It took a lot of going back and fort to fix that issue. There used to be way of checking if pointer is in range of memory given to the program, idk if it is still possible, but that will not prevent you from overwriting your own code and causing segfault anyways.

Answer (score 2):

The common way is to always initialize pointers to NULL when you first declare them or after freeing them so that whenever you have to manipulate a pointer, if it's equal to `NULL`, you know that you have to allocate them and populate their data.